# Php get request doesnt work

Tags: php, forms, get, smarty

could you please help me, 
I am editing a smarty template with bootstrap controls and want to make a simple php form, with get method.
however when the button is clicked the form isn't submitted, the url in browser just adds '?' and no key-values are added after.

Please take a look, tell me what am i doing wrong,
thx!

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <form method="get" role="form" name="form">
        <div class='row'>
            <p class="col-md-2"> Количество членов партии:</p>
            <div class='col-md-2'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="from" class="col-sm-1">{'От'|t}:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" id='from' class='form-control'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='col-md-2'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="to" class="col-sm-1">{'До'|t}:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" id='to' class='form-control'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type='submit' value='{"Фильтр"|t}' />
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: post the complete html opening form tag is missing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "name" for input.

```
<input type="text" id='to' name='to' class='form-control'>
```

After request is executed, "name" will be shown in url:

http://someurl.sk/action?to=[valueFromInputWwithName'to']

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to create form.

Please add `<form name="">`

Also, check that all your fields have `name` attributes.

in your code.

Comment: It was included just don't know why it wasn't displayed at first attempt.